# What happened to file descriptor 4 and 5?

Tags: php, internals

If you open a file with PHP from CLI and retrieve the file descriptor:

```
$fp = fopen("somefile", "r"); 
echo 0 + $fp;
```

you get the surprising result of 5. Running from `mod_php` in Apache you get the expected 3. I know 0 is `STDIN`, 1 is `STDOUT`, 2 is `STDERR` but when I try to open `php://fd/3` and `php://fd/4` I get an error suggesting they do not exist.

The result does not change whether I try a file on disk or `php://memory` instead of `somefile`. Nor does it change if I use `php -r` or `php x.php`.

So what happens to the file descriptors 3 and 4? Is there some interesting feature lurking in there I am unaware of, some stream wrapper that exist only in some circumstance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. It's file descriptor 3, just as you would have thought.

```
strace -etrace=open php -r '$fp = fopen("somefile", "r"); echo 0 + $fp;'
[…]
open("/home/username/somefile", O_RDONLY)   = 3
5+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Coercing a PHP resource, such as a file handle, to an integer gives you its PHP resource identifier, not its file descriptor. Resource numbers are allocated starting with 1, not 0; when running in the CLI, the first three are always allocated for the `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` streams. While there's some correspondence with file descriptors, this is coincidental, and breaks down when you start considering non-file resources such as MySQL results or streams that aren't backed by a file handle (like memory, or complex wrappers).

(I'm not sure what the fourth resource is used for under the CLI. There's no way to get a resource by its ID, so discovering what it is would be difficult.)

Comment: Fourth. Under the CLI, resource #1 is STDIN, #2 is STDOUT, #3 is STDERR, #4 is a mystery, and #5 is the first one you open. There isn't a #0, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Oh resources count from 1 not 0? Also, how can Apache return then 3?